# What can you do against a fed Fizz?

Tags: league-of-legends

A couple games ago, one of my teammates (Vladimir) Fed a Fizz 9 times. I played Kog'Maw and since Fizz can pretty much jump over my front line and own me, there was nothing I could do. What can you do against a fed Fizz?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several measures you can take against a fed Fizz:

- Ranged poke him
- Focus CC on him during team fights
- Get GA/banshee
- Dodge his ult
- Get magic resist

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't much you can do 1v1. Best thing to do is try to catch him alone with your team, will be hard with troll pole though, he can get away easy.